# SQL compare date return wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, date, comparison

I'm trying to get the dates after a given date, let's say `2014:06:24 18:27:15` so here's my query :

```
SELECT 
    collected, 
    ip 
FROM syslogs 
WHERE date_format(collected, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%k:%s') > date_format('2014:06:24 18:27:15', '%Y:%m:%d %H:%k:%s') 
ORDER BY collected DESC
```

And the output gives me this :

```
[...]
24/06/2014 18:22:16 192.168.0.12
24/06/2014 18:22:16 192.168.0.12
24/06/2014 18:21:54 192.168.0.12
24/06/2014 18:21:54 192.168.0.12
24/06/2014 18:21:39 192.168.0.12
24/06/2014 18:21:39 192.168.0.12
24/06/2014 18:21:34 192.168.0.12
[...]
```

Which means that it return some lines which are **before** the wanted time. How is that possible ?

Comment: Why are you using `DATE_FORMAT()` for date comparison in the first place?

Comment: 3 is greater than 1, in just the same way that 3+2 is greater than 1+2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you using "k" for minutes. "k" is for hour according [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) and it is inputted 27 which is outside if hour boundaries.

Comment: And here's the official documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Actually, the real problem is that you are comparing strings instead of dates.

Comment: @DanBracuk what? how ?